# How to change initcwnd with every reboot?

Tags: debian, networking, ip, network-interface

I can change the `initcwnd`([TCP initial congestion window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion_control)) of my Debian linux system with the command:

```
ip route change default via 123.123.123.241 dev eno1 onlink initcwnd 32
```

Example:

```
$ ip route show
default via 123.123.123.241 dev eno1 onlink 
123.123.123.240/29 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 123.123.123.242 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
$ ip route change default via 123.123.123.241 dev eno1 onlink initcwnd 32
$ ip route show
default via 123.123.123.241 dev eno1 onlink  initcwnd 32
123.123.123.240/29 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 123.123.123.242 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
$
```

How can I keep this change after a reboot? Here's my `/etc/network/interfaces`. Is this the right place to add this config? How?

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
  address 123.123.123.242
  netmask 255.255.255.248
  network 123.123.123.240
  broadcast 123.123.123.29
  gateway 123.123.123.241
  dns-nameservers 123.123.1.2 123.123.1.66

auto eno1:0
iface eno1:0 inet static
  address 123.123.123.243
  netmask 255.255.255.248
  gateway 123.123.123.241
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a `post-up`-command to the `eno1` section in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
iface eno1 inet static
  ...
  dns-nameservers 123.123.1.2 123.123.1.66
  post-up ip route change default via 123.123.123.241 dev eno1 onlink initcwnd 32

iface eno0:2 inet static
  ...
```

[Many more details about Debian network configuration](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration)